# hasMany for one table and return Main model collection laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship

hi and thanks for answer.
there is fields table. each field has many related fields that save in related_fields table. so related_fields table has tow columns:

```
field_id, related_field
```

I use this code for get related_fields:

```
    public function linked(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\RelatedField','field_id','related_field');
}
```

but the problem is that this function returns RelatedField collection as result not Fields collection and that is not needed and Fields collection is needed.
what is the best way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `HasManyThrough` relationship. Add a `fields` method on the `Field` model:

```
// Field.php
public function fields()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(App\Field::class, App\RelatedField::class, 'field_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: thanks. but I got this error:
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fields.related_field'

Comment: Change  `related_field` to `id`, that should line it up with the `fields` table.

Comment: Tanks But one question: how laravel detected related_field?

Comment: The 3rd and 4th arguments allow you to specify the foreign key and primary key of the joining table and targeted table, respectively. Eloquent does a lot of it's work by naming conventions, too, so what goes under the hood is often times hidden from the user.